# Confusion with a simple git rebase

Tags: git

I'm trying to follow an example based on the GitPro book: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing, but I'm not getting the same output generated and I'm pretty confused.

If I have a single text file, checkout a new branch, and make edits:

```
$ git branch
* master

$ git checkout -b test
Switched to a new branch 'test'

$ echo "one change" > my_file.txt 
$ git commit -am "Change one"

 echo "another change" > my_file.txt 
$ git commit -am "Change two"
```

At this stage, GitPro says that if you run `rebase` in this branch, the output will be

```
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: added staged command
```

but, when I run it

```
$ git rebase master
Current branch test is up to date.
```

and when I return to master, and merge, it does fast-forward but all the commits from the branch are shown in the log

```
commit ac492923dc11ac50c43b55afe639210a4b665130 (HEAD -> master, test)
Author: Chris <chris@localhost>
Date:   Sun Jun 7 18:26:22 2020 +0100

    Change two

commit 6c5887a51abc30530edbe18d4c9b4c31756f6ffc
Author: Chris <chris@localhost>
Date:   Sun Jun 7 18:25:50 2020 +0100

    Change one
```

GitPro suggests that these commits shouldn't be in the log. So, what's going on, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do the commit `Change one` on master branch and the commit `Change two` on test branch. That way your `master` branch and `test` branch will diverge by one commit. Then you can `rebase` your `test` branch and see the desired output.

Comment: @mnestorov right, so `Current branch test is up to date.` is git's way of saying there are merges to be made?

Comment: When do you get that message? After rebase? up-to-date with the branch means "up-to-date" with the local ref called origin/test

Comment: @mnestorov I get it _when_ I  run `git rebase master`

Comment: In that case it just means that there isn't anything to merge between test and master. Test is after master, so it technically is up to date and it also is the same as origin/test

Comment: @matt yes, you're absolutely right. The git-scm site doesn't have _any_ files tho so it's pretty difficult to show how things change without creating one

Comment: @matt I assume you downvoted? I think a suggestion of a change of title, rather than a downvote, would be more useful

Comment: @matt sorry, but I disagree (and that's my professional view as a teacher). I used the same commands given, and got a different outcome. I understand now why that is, thanks to mnestorov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `master` and `test` diverge, so that one can rebase on the other.

The first the commit `Change one` can be put on `master` branch and the commit `Change two` on the `test` branch. That way your `master` branch and `test` branch will diverge by one commit. Then you can do this while on `test`

```
git rebase master
```

And you'll see the desired output.